# How to add uniqueness on many to many using through on column of other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have two models `Company`, `Asset` and a join model `CompanyAsset` and the association is as follows:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_assets
  has_many :assets, through: :company_assets    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_assets, allow_destroy: true
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_assets
  has_many :companies, through: :company_assets

  validates :label, uniqueness: true
end

class CompanyAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :asset
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I want to validate uniqueness of `label` attribute of `Asset` such that uniqueness is specific to `Company`.

For ex: There is *Company-A* and *Company-B*.

*Company-A* has one `Asset` with `label` *Asset-A*. Now system should allow me to create *Asset-A* for *Company-B* but should not allow to create *Asset-A* again for *Company-A*.

`validates :label, uniqueness: true` will not allow to create `Asset`with same label in any `Company`

I am creating `Asset` records

```
a =  Company.find(1) // Company-A
a.update(company_assets_attributes: [{info: 'pqr', asset_attributes: {label: 'Asset A'}}])
```

Now I want to create *Asset-A* for *Company-B*

```
b = Company.find(2) // Company-B
b.update(company_assets_attributes: [{info: 'abc', asset_attributes: {label: 'Asset A'}}])
```

Any thoughts on how to handle the uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ActiveRecord custom validator on label which does a lookup for same label, company_id pairs.

On CompanyAsset:

```
validate :asset_label_must_be_unique
  def asset_label_must_be_unique
    errors.add(:base, 'Must unique') unless CompanyAsset.joins(:assets).where('assets.label' => asset.label).where(company_id: company_id).none?
  end
```

Comment: `label` is attribute of `asset` & not of the `company_asset`, so this won't work.

Comment: Sorry bout that Salil.  Just modified the post.

Comment: This will work same as `validates :label, uniqueness: true`, but i want uniqueness specific to `Company`

Comment: Then you can join off the CompanyAsset directly rather than the instance - updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

> validates :label, uniqueness: { scope: :company_id }